# ngModel does not get the value of the input

Tags: ionic-framework, input, ionic3, console.log, ngmodel

**PLEASE HELP.**

I got this lines of code on my app, the value of the input here comes from the firebase database. That works as the value is shown when I ran the app. My problem is when i console.log(attendance.studentName). It doesnt get the value. It is null or {}.

> HTML

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let student of studentList$ | async">
    <!-- problem here, ngModel -->
    <ion-input [ngModel]="attendance.studentName" [value]="student.name"></ion-input>

    <ion-select item-end [ngModel]="attendance.status">
      <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Late">Late</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

> TS

```
attendance = {} as Attendance

export class CheckAttendancePage {

  studentList$: Observable<Student[]>
  attendance = {} as Attendance 

  constructor(private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private studentsList: StudentListService, private attendanceList: AttendanceListService, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.studentList$ = this.studentsList
      .getStudentList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(
        changes => {
          return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
        }))
      }
    )
  }

  addAttendance(attendance: Attendance){
    console.log(attendance)    
  }
```

> MODEL

```
export interface Attendance {
    key?: string;
    studentName: string;
    status: string;
}
```

> SERVICE

```
@Injectable()
export class AttendanceListService {

  private attendanceListRef = this.db.list<Attendance>('attendance')
  private studentListRef = this.db.list<Student>('students-list')

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){}

  getStudentsList() { 
    return this.studentListRef;
  }
```

**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: You should use `ngModel` like this `[(ngModel)]` for two way binding data

Comment: Care to explain these one-way binding and two-way binding?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using different names for ngModel and value property of input.
The syntax you are using won't work try using these syntax :

with ngModel:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let student of studentList$ | async">
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="student.name></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

OR without shorthand syntax on input

```
<ion-input [ngModel]="student.name" (ngModelChange)="student.name = $event" </ion-input>
```

without ngModel directive:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let student of studentList$ | async">
    <ion-input [value]="student.name" (input)="student.name = $event.target.value"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Because the value of the ion-input comes from the firebase database, not from the input of the user. In short, the permanent value of each ion-input comes from the database. Is there any way I can work around on this?

Comment: So tell me do you want to just display the value or you want to change them(edit) after you display as you are using input field to display the values

Comment: I want to display the value and I dont want the user to edit the input as the purpose of my app is to actually check if that user (on input) is present or absent. I didnt include the select tag on the post I I'll edit it. @Mahesh

Comment: So do you want to display the name in input element only or a normal ionic list would also be ok

Comment: Can I push the value using ionic list?

Comment: Where do you want to push and where ... Do you want to add new students using input

Comment: No no. the value of the input comes from firebase. The page's purpose is to check attendance. I fetch the students from firebase then put these all on input. Then using the ion-select I can set if they're absent or present etc. Then after that I want to push these on firebase. Sorry I'm new to Ionic

Comment: Ok you can do one thing in the input field use same ngModel student.name and input also and on ion select use a new property called student.status instead of attendance.status so after you finish all the checking of absent and presents you can get all the data inside the same studentList array and then you can push that array inside firebase

Comment: Okay wait. I'll try to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Check my answer sir. I dont know how to assign the firebase student value on constructor

Comment: No need to assign anything say when you finish updating all the students status details you might be using a button to submit or save to firebase right then inside that function log the already present this.studentList array and check if you have a new property inside every student called status then you can do what you want to do with that list

Comment: I have no idea how to do that sir. can you pleade show me how to do what youre talking about?

Comment: sir?? I really need your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the value of the input..

> html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let student of studentList$ | async">

  <!-- problem here, ngModel -->  
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="attendance.studentName" [value]="attendance.name" type="text" disabled="true">{{student.name}}</ion-input>

  <ion-select item-end [ngModel]="attendance.status">
    <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Late">Late</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

> ts

attendance: any = {
    'studentName': '',
    'status': ''
  }

> then on constructor

```
  this.attendance.studentName = "asdasd"
```

My problem here is that the value of the this.attendance.studentName should come from firebase. And I don't know how to do that.